# IE8 Table not correctly sizing <td>

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've been working on this site for quite a while, and I've finally got it looking pretty nice I think.  But I've noticed a problem with the home page on IE8 (no other browser has this problem that i've used)

in IE8, the site looks like this: [image: the blue bars around the td are created by the HTML analyzer and help show the problem]

Notice the blue bars on the sides of the far right column, they show how wide the `<td>` is.  the content within is 160px as it should be, but the `<td>` itself is wider than it should be.  As you can see in the HTML analyzer on the left, the width is set to "160", however the HTML in the page says:

```
<td style="width: 160px;max-width:160px"width="160px"align="center"valign="top">
```

Out of Desperation I've tried a few things obviously.  Why does IE continue to hate me?  What code can I write to make IE play nice like the rest of the browsers do?

The actual site URL is http://EpicClanWars.com if you wish to dig into source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `table-layout: fixed` to the `<table>`'s style. Without it, applying `width` to a table cell is interpreted as `min-width` (a carryover from when `min-width` didn't exist)

Comment: Also, consider using `box-sizing: border-box` because you have elements with the width you want but coming wider because of padding and border.